# References for effects of constant imputation

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

I have recently seen people simply adding a constant value in missing data before using regular statistical procedures, but those choices are not argued or do not have any resemblance to the rest of the data (e.g. putting $0$ or $\infty$ always instead of mean or median). From the literature I know, such situations are not even taking into consideration, but it is still a practice I encounter. Of course, it induces lots of bias, but some people I discussed with argue that it is not so important.

Does anyone know about references of the effects of constant imputation on statistical procedures?